# Is there a modern standard for creating block diagrams or flowcharts?

Tags: flowchart

On various pages on the Internet I read about flowcharts and tried to find information about what block diagram symbols I can use in various situations/contexts.

I found the standard created by [ECMA-4](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-WITHDRAWN/ECMA-4,%202nd%20Edition,%20September%201966.pdf) and IBM, but the first is from 1966 and the second from 1970. It means that some symbols are outdated like magnetic tape symbol or punched card symbol.

I'm curious if a more modern standard exists.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Flowcharts are rarely used anymore. Look into UML in general, and Activity Diagrams in particular.

Comment: The last time I did a flowchart was 1979. I had always found them completely useless. They over-emphasis the decisions and under-emphasise the processing.

Answer (score 1):

I use Microsoft Visio and it gives you access to a complete Library of different standards you can use. There are entire sections for Software, Databases, etc.

With the Libraries provided by Visio you can create UML Class Diagrams and/or Entity Relationship Diagrams for your OO Programs and their associated back ends after having designed them using the appropriate Software Engineering principles that I think you are trying to apply.

check it out. its the best solution that I have found.